# selenium wait few second and run execute next line code

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I want add wait time of 5 seconds  and run next line

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/bookking-
navbar/nav/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li[1]/authentication/a/span")).click();

String value=  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*
   [@id='username']")).getText();
```

here i want add 5 second wait then run next line if use thread.sleep(500) the web page loading too much time

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='username']")).clear();

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='username']")).sendKeys(value);

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("apple123");


driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/divdiv/button")).click();
```

Comment: Selenium works with a number of languages. Please add tag for the driver you're using.

Comment: Can i know why you need to wait for 5 seconds

Comment: You don't have to put your code to sleep. Set Selenium time out instead. That way it will keep trying to find a tag for several seconds before raising an exception.

Comment: @santhoshkumar  im using  get text command  (manually want to enter )  its need 5 second that why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make thread sleep:

> Thread.sleep(5000);

But that is not a good decision to make such sleeps, as your tests will be very slow. Use webdriver waits instead:

> WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);
>       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("xpathHere")));

It will wait until `elementToBeClickable` (or you can choose any other condition) and continue test execution. Otherwise, if a condition is not met during a timeout - exception will be thrown.

**Update:**
If you write UI regression tests using selenium + java, it's highly recommended to use [Selenide framework](http://selenide.org/). Here is 10 min start tutorial: https://vimeo.com/107647158

- It's fully integrated with pure selenium
- manages WebDriver on its own (if you want you can pass your WebDriver setup by `WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(driver);`)
- have really easy to use and read syntax, like this: `$("#elementId").pressEnter().should(disappear);`
- and what is important on this topic - it has easy to use waits, like :

> ```
> $(By.id("elId")).waitUntil(attribute("attr", "expectedValued"), 5000);
> $(By.id("elId")).should(matchText("Text to match"));
> ```

So initial code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='username']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='username']")).sendKeys(value);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("apple123");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/divdiv/button")).click();
```

With Selenide will look like (all waits included):

```
$("#username").shouldBe(visible).setValue(value);
$("#password").shouldBe(visible).setValue("apple123");
$(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/divdiv/button")).shouldBe(visible).setValue("apple123");
```